# Trying to count user inputted string less spaces, commas, and periods in Python

Tags: python

I am completely and utterly novice at this. But here goes.

the assignment is to count the characters in a user input string, but not count the spaces, periods, and commas.

It just won't ignore the spaces.

This is my first term doing a scripting class, and I am almost certain I'm missing something ridiculously obvious. But I can't see it right now.

It's mostly working. It counts the characters. It ignores the periods and commas.

I've tried searching it up, but every solution I've seen is stuff we haven't covered yet (to the best of my memory), and I don't suspect the instructor would have thrown us something we haven't done yet.

This is what I have so far:

```
user_text = input()
char_count = 0
for character in user_text:
    if character != ' ' or ',' or '.':
        char_count += 1
        continue
    elif character == ' ' or ',' or '.':
        pass
print(char_count)
```

Comment: `character != ' ' or ',' or '.'` is not doing what you think.  Python splits that into three separate sub-expressions: `character != ' '` and `','` and `'.'`.  The second and third sub-expressions are plain non-empty strings which always evaluate as true.

Comment: it's the way the if is written either use 3 times != or use character not in and the list of characters to ignore. The elif part is useless